# Where is the hostfile located?

Tags: ssh, localhost

working on setting up a local development environment. Im pretty new to Linux. I am using Virtualbox for Ubuntu server inside of the Ubuntu Desktop I am running. After setting up port forwarding I am able to connect to it using these commands: `ssh -p2222 user@127.0.0.1`
or
`ssh -p user@localhost`.

I like to connect to it using ssh user@example.hostname. I understood that I would be able to do that by simply adding this line to my hostfile:
`127.0.0.1 example.hostname`.

The problem is, I dont know where to find this file. Where is the hostfile located on Ubuntu Desktop 14.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you're looking for is `/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 1):

For `ssh` you can use `~/.ssh/config` and configure shorthand access to host like this:

```
Host example.hostname
HostName 127.0.0.1
User user
Port 2222
```

If you have bash completion then it would be sufficient to type `ssh ex<Tab>` to auto-complete to `ssh example.hostname` and by running this command your ssh will try to connect to host specified in `HostName` (ip or hostname) with user `user` and port `2222`